# Angular, how to check if Post is done. ToPromise() and subscribe() not working

Tags: angular, post, promise

I don't know why (it is my first time trying it) but even though my post request is working I am not able to print anything AFTER is done.

In the TS file this is my code:

```js
this.appService.sendPath({ title: serviceToPath }).toPromise().then
(
  ()=>
  {
    console.log("The path is set!")
  }
);
```

Then this is "appService" my middle man

```js
sendPath(path: any): Observable<any> {
   console.log("path from app-service: "+ JSON.stringify(path))
   return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/compare',path)
}
```

Of course the console message "The path is set!" never displays on the console while "path from app-service" works perfectly.

The final aim would be to call a function after the POST has finished its things but for now, I want just to print something on the console.

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE:**
It seems that is because my Post request is in a forever pending state. How can I fix this?

Comment: the code looks correct. are you sure the execution ever rich the code which calls `this.appService.sendPath`?

Comment: Remote `toPromise()`, use `.subscribe` and pass an error handler to check if any error occurs: `this.appService.sendPath({ title: serviceToPath }).subscribe(() => console.log('The path is set!'), (error: any) => console.log('Error setting path:', error));`

Comment: @IAfanasov That's why is so weird indeed. Yes, it gets executed because "path from app-service: " gets displayed correctly.

Comment: @MichaelD I just tried the subscribe + the error but no error pops up:

`this.appService.sendPath({ title: serviceToPath }).subscribe( res=>  {
        console.log("The path is set!")
      }, error =>
      {
        console.log("Sending is wrong " + error)
      }
    );`

Comment: could it be that BE is slow? do you see the request in the Network tab of the dev tools?

Comment: @IAfanasovI do see a couple of things going to the right route being "pending"

Comment: @IAfanasov indeed now that I am having a proper look at the network it seems that the constantly pending request is exactly the post request. But that's weird because I know that the Service is receiving the data. How is this possible and how to solve it? thanks for your time

Comment: hm... usually `pending` means `server hasn't responded yet`. I don't have any strong ideas on how is it possible. I suppose it would be nice to try calling some other server. It could tell us if the problem is the server of the frontend app.

Comment: Thanks a lot @IAfanasov for your help, it is really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it was the server-side that was wrong. Thanks again to IAfanasov who gave me a quite big clue!

```
//If you forget this the promise will not work and you will never know when POST is over
res.status(205).send('');
```

I wasn't sending the status so the frontend-promise couldn't know when was over.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just subscribing to your function ?

```
this.appService.sendPath({ title: serviceToPath })
.subscribe(res => {
  console.log("The path is set!")
});
```

Comment: I tried but also that one seems not working. Could it be that I got to import something weird in my modules?

Comment: Do you see the POST request execution from the "Network" tab ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am a newbie. Although I do see some stuff (some of them pending) including some Preflight stuff going into the right Route and as I said the post itself is posting (those paths leads to images that get displayed correctly) so I do not get why is not working.